# Under which school does the teachings of Brahma Kumaris fall under?

Tags: teaching

I am unable to narrow it down to Sankhya or yoga or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Brahkumari site does not name any individual as Guru of their fouder.So they do not seem to have a Guru-parampara.Normally the school is judged by the lineage. It seemes that it stated with their founder. So far as I know, they have revised the Gita also. So I do not think they belong strictly to any classical or Sanatana school.

http://www.brahmakumaris.org/about-us/the-brahma-kumaris-story/brahma-baba-the-founder